# Updated React to V16.1.1 & other dependencies to latest versions

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I updated my web application to the latest version of React V16.1.1.

Along with that I updated all the latest dependencies like webpack, babel etc.

The webpack compiles & throws no error on compile time, but on run time, I am facing with the below mentioned error shown in the console window.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bool' of undefined
at Object.defineProperty.value (influencerApp.js?ver=1511878497:48295)
at __webpack_require__ (influencerApp.js?ver=1511878497:20)
at Object.defineProperty.value (influencerApp.js?ver=1511878497:21935)
at __webpack_require__ (influencerApp.js?ver=1511878497:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (influencerApp.js?ver=1511878497:101593)
at __webpack_require__ (influencerApp.js?ver=1511878497:20)
at Object.defineProperty.value (influencerApp.js?ver=1511878497:101488)
at __webpack_require__ (influencerApp.js?ver=1511878497:20)
at Object.defineProperty.value (influencerApp.js?ver=1511878497:100898)
at __webpack_require__ (influencerApp.js?ver=1511878497:20)
```

PS: The app was working fine before the upgrade, does anyone know why this could be happening?

I am unable to find a solution for the same can any body help.

Thank you.

Comment: @Leandro: I updated it from V15. I just updated react-bootstrap & it started working, I looked into the code & it was showing some error related to transition.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, It got resolved.

I updated react-bootstrap to the latest version & it started working.

Thank you.